# What is wrong while, Iterating through the array?

Tags: javascript

In the `for` loop i'm iterating through the array of strings and meanwhile changing the `src` of image but, `setTimeout` method is not holding `myfun` for 3000 ms because of this the for loop just iterate in a blink of any eye to the last string of array. Where I'm going wrong?

```
<script>
 function myfunction(){
 var arr = ["mind.jpg","images.jpg","external.jpg"];
 var image = document.getElementById("IMAGE");

 for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
    setTimeout(myfun,3000);      
    image.src = arr[i];

 }
 }   
 function myfun(){

 }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the intended (and most usefull) bevahiour of `setTimeout` - it puts some function to event loop and continue running, making it possible to run functions asyncronically.

Comment: It's `setTimeout`, an asynchronous method, not a `sleep` method that blocks everything.

Comment: `setTimeout` executes the callback after the delay (in your case the callback is `myfun`. If you want to set `image.src` on a delay, you should do it from within the callback, however you will also need to use a closure to capture the value of `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make something like slideshow, you need to do it like this:

```
function myfunction() {
    var arr = ["mind.jpg","images.jpg","external.jpg"];
    var image = document.getElementById("IMAGE");
    var i = 0;
    function next() {
        image.src = arr[i];
        if(++i === arr.length) {
            i = 0
        }
    }
    setInterval(next, 3000)
}
```

Comment: I think `var i` is going out of bound

Comment: ohh !, u already edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    myfun(i);
}

function myfun(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        image.src = arr[i];
    }, 3000 * i);
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myfun(i);
}

function myfun(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.write(i + '<br>');
    }, 1000 * i);
}
```

Comment: This solution would not work: it will execute 3 functions after 3 seconds almost at the same time

Comment: @NikolaiMavrenkov Are you sure? see snippet below

Comment: Or, I'm sorry, I missed the multiplication for time

Comment: @NikolaiMavrenkov it's OK :)